# MongoDB - range based sharding command

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongoengine

I have been reading about MongoDB's range based sharding and want to apply that to my collection with the following rules. All EntityId fields < 1000 must go to shard 1, EntityId fields between 1001 and 2000 should go to shard 2 and for other EntityId values, go to shard 3. Wonder how the sh.shardCollection looks like for this? I couldn't find an example for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the command sh.splitAt after sh.shardCollection  to get it done. There may be must robust solutions.